# Android widget, start intent

Tags: android, android-widget, android-intent

I'm trying to make an Android widget, to show some info from my app.

I have succeed to show some info, but know i what to have a feature to "switch page" in my app. It means pressing a button, and new info is showing. But how do i do it? I have tried different thing, and I'm ending up with the following code:

```
public class HelloWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    RemoteViews remoteViews;

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "onUpdate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(TestReceiver.TEST_INTENT);
        intent.setClassName(TestReceiver.class.getPackage().getName(), TestReceiver.class.getName());
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.bbutton1, pendingIntent);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widgetTxt, "The textview");
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[0], remoteViews);

        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }

    public class TestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public static final String TEST_INTENT = "MyTestIntent";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "You reached the TestReceiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (intent.getAction() == TEST_INTENT) {
                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widgetTxt, "Is changed");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED.equals(action)) {
            final int appWidgetId = intent.getExtras().getInt(
                    AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                    AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
            if (appWidgetId != AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
                this.onDeleted(context, new int[] { appWidgetId });
            }
        } else {
            super.onReceive(context, intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "onDelete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
    }
}
```

Toast are showing "onUpdate" and then i remove it at "onDeleted". The textview also change in the onUpdate, but nothing happens when i press the button.

My Manifest look like this:

```
    <receiver android:name=".HelloWidget" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/hello_widget_provider" />
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".TestReceiver" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="MyTestIntent">
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is your TestReceiver an inner class of HelloWidget?

Then you didn't specify the correct name in the manifest.